# Vary color across plot points

Tags: matlab

The following code plots 3 points, all in red:

```
a = reshape([92.571251 94.869889 97.283709 ],[3  1]);
b = reshape([271.000000 296.000000 330.000000 ],[3  1]);
c = reshape([0.916000 0.766000 0.562000 ],[3  1]);
figure(100);
line(b,a,...
    'MarkerFaceColor',[1 0 0],...
    'Marker','o',...
    'LineStyle','none',...
    'Color',[1 0 0]);
```

Is there a way for me to vectorize the red portion of the 'Color' plot style using 'c' such that the first point uses c(1) to replace the 1 so that the color is [0.916 0 0], etc.?

NOTE: This code is a snippet of something much larger that will likely plot 100's or 1000's of points over time on the same plot. I need the color for each point to be set when it's placed on the plot and then not change as other points are added. (If possible)

I do not think a color map is appropriate as I may plot points at the same X,Y coordinates at different times. Sometimes they will be bright, other times dim.

Just trying to not use a loop which would be relatively straight forward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To colorize the points (and only the points, not the lines in between), you can use the `MarkerFaceColor` property of the `scatter` function (or `scatter3` in 3D).

For instance:

```
scatter(a, b, 'MarkerFaceColor', rgb)
```

where rgb are RGB triplets, or

```
scatter(a, b, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'flat', 'CData', c)
```

with `c` being a vector of values. In this case the colors are mapped onto the current colormap and the range is controled by `caxis`.

If you want lines between your points, you can simply use a code like this:

```
hold on
plot(a, b, '-')
scatter(...)
```

Best,

Comment: Unable to make your exact response work here but the pointer to scatter led to to the start of a solution using "scatter(a, b,[], col3, 'filled');" where col is the rgb triplet and the [] says skip setting the size. I think scatter will do what I need so I'm accepting your answer as is and will try to get it to actually work later. Thanks!